# get data from layers of div returns repeated texts SELENIUM JAVA

Tags: java, html, selenium, maven, testng

i am trying to get some texts from a layered div. 2 are returning correct texts but the last is just coming out repeatedly, please point me to where i am making mistakes

```
public static void get_Data_() throws IOException {
        List<WebElement> urls = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("this_is_container_div"));

        for(WebElement e: urls) {
            List<WebElement> img_html = e.findElements(By.xpath("//my_img_xpath"));
            List<WebElement> title_html = e.findElements(By.cssSelector(".my_title_selector"));
            String num = urls.get(0).getAttribute("this_is_num");
            String title = title_html.get(0).getText();
            String image = img_html.get(0).getAttribute("src");
            System.out.println( num +" " +title+" "+image);
```

So, the first two i.e 'num' and 'title' are working fine but the last one which is image is coming out repeatedly.
The HTML code would be something like this:

```
    <html>
    <div num-data_1="this_is_container_div">

      <span>src = "this_is_the_image_url_1"</span>
          <span>num = "this_is_num_1"</span>
            <div class="my_title_selector_1">title</div>
      <span>src = "this_is_the_image_url_2"</span>
          <span>num = "this_is_num_2"</span>
            <div class="my_title_selector_2">title</div>
      <span>src = "this_is_the_image_url_3"</span>
          <span>num = "this_is_num_3"</span>
            <div class="my_title_selector_3">title</div>
      <span>src = "this_is_the_image_url_4"</span>
          <span>num = "this_is_num_4"</span>
            <div class="my_title_selector_4">title</div>
    </>div>
    </html>
```

And this is example of outcome:

1. this_is_num_001, title_001, this_is_the_image_url_1
2. this_is_num_002, title_002, this_is_the_image_url_1
3. this_is_num_003, title_003, this_is_the_image_url_1
4. this_is_num_004, title_004, this_is_the_image_url_1

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: the output doesn't match the code. Did you attempt to change it before posting?

Comment: hi, yes, i changed it. i will post the html now

Comment: Can you try this List<WebElement> img_html = e.findElements(By.xpath(".//my_img_xpath")); to search only inside the node. If that doesnt work we really need the html. Edit the ticket and post it there from parent to children. The one that you added in the comment its not a valid html.

Comment: @art_architect, thanks a million !! i figured it out by just typing "." as you suggested.. issue is resolved. i wish i could buy you some beer, you cant imagine how much time i have wasted trying to figure this out....thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

public static void get_Data_() throws IOException {
List urls = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("this_is_container_div"));

```
    for(WebElement e: urls) {
        List<WebElement> img_html = e.findElements(By.xpath(".//my_img_xpath"));
        List<WebElement> title_html = e.findElements(By.cssSelector(".my_title_selector"));
        String num = e.getAttribute("this_is_num");
        String title = title_html.get(0).getText();
        String image = img_html.get(0).getAttribute("src");
        System.out.println( num +" " +title+" "+image);
```